# How can I change this script to point to a different file location

Tags: php, directory

I installed a shopping cart in a subfolder called "cart". The index for the shopping cart is located in that folder as well and I want to use it as my homepage (index) in the main directory of the website. I've copied the index.php file from the cart to the main directory of the site, but I need to have the code point to the files back in the 'Cart' folder. At least that's my assumption on how to get the index file to work as my homepage for the site.

```
require dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'ini.inc.php';
define('CC_IN_ADMIN', false);

global $config_default;

include CC_ROOT_DIR.CC_DS.'controllers'.CC_DS.'controller.index.inc.php';

$htmlout = $GLOBALS['smarty']->fetch('templates/'.$global_template_file);
$htmlout = ($GLOBALS['gui']->disableJS) ? preg_replace('~<\s*\bscript\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*script\s*>~is', '', $htmlout) : $htmlout;

$googleAnalytics = isset($googleAnalytics) ? $googleAnalytics : '';
$htmlout = preg_replace('/(\<\/head\>)/i',$googleAnalytics.'$1', $htmlout);
die($htmlout);
```

Comment: Is it possible to unpack the "cart" folder straight into your web root? Otherwise you're facing a potentially arduous tasks of editing every single `include` or `require` in the cart's code.

Comment: Where's the error/issue? Does what you tried not work?